# Add "shadow" to view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have cells with 2 "rectangles". What i want is, add shadow to right rectangle. It will be better explained on screenshot:

[image]

From left is first part of cell (first rectangle) and on a right in second part. I want to add a shadow that look like on a screenshot. I tried:

```
-(void)addInnerShadow{



    self.bgDetailsView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#a4c2e0"].CGColor;
    self.bgDetailsView.layer.shadowOffset = (CGSize){SHADOW_SIDE_HEIGHT,0};
    //    self.vSelectionBack.layer.shadowRadius = 1.4;
    self.bgDetailsView.layer.shadowRadius = SHADOW_SIDE_HEIGHT;
    self.bgDetailsView.layer.shadowOpacity = .5;
}
```

Where bgDetailsView is second (right) view, but it has no effect.

Comment: what is `SHADOW_SIDE_HEIGHT`'s value?

Comment: @Mr.UB its 8    ...

Comment: To avoid performance shot your can put in cell image looking like shadow. If you have a lot of cells, performance impact with shadows on layer will be quite big.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as I understand you want to add shadow to right view and shadow casts over the left view.

**To do so:**

You can set `self.bgDetailsView.clipsToBounds = NO`, it will make shadow visible but will also make your shadow to be visible over and below the right view.

You can put right view in container. Set `clipsToBounds = NO` in right view and make container view a bit bigger to the left.

You can also make a container view with additional `CALayer` or `UIImageView` with shadow image. Put your right view to right of this additional view/layer and set in container `clipsToBounds = NO`.

You can also use `shadowPath` property of right view layer and put it in container view:

```
self.bgDetailsView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowRect].CGPath;
```